# Processing sketch does not render properly in web browser

Tags: html, processing, processing.js

I have a processing sketch that I have embedded into an `.html` document by using a canvas and `processing.js`. The sketch renders perfectly fine when I hit play in processing. But when I embed it in a webpage, the circles that are drawn seem to be displaced, among other things. Here's a [link](http://iremaltan.com/test.html) to the webpage.

**EDIT: It turns out the `resize()` function was not working properly on the browser.(See the resize function not working [here](http://iremaltan.com/test3.html)) Does the resize function work by creating a temp file of the resized image, or something of that sort?**

Below is the processing code:

```
PImage img;

int X = (int) 1000;
int Y = (int) X/16*9;
int r = 5;
int gridX = X/r;
int gridY = Y/r;

void setup(){
  String url = "http://iremaltan.com/pde/robb2/data/robb.jpg";
  noStroke();
  size(X,Y);
  img = loadImage(url,"jpg");
  img.resize(X,Y);
  img.loadPixels();
  frameRate(500);
  background(0);
}

int xLoc,yLoc;
float gray;
int i=0;
void draw(){
  xLoc = (i%gridX)*r+r/2;
  yLoc = i/(gridX)*r+r/2;
  gray = colorRetriever(xLoc,yLoc);
  fill(gray);
  ellipse(xLoc,yLoc,r,r);
  fill(255,0,0);
  i++; 
}

float colorRetriever(int xLoc, int yLoc){
  int pix = (yLoc-1)*X+xLoc-1;
  float gray;
  float r = red(img.pixels[pix]);
  float g = green(img.pixels[pix]);
  float b = blue(img.pixels[pix]);
  gray=(r+g+b)/3;
  return(gray);
}
```

Also here is the relevant `html` code, just in case there's a problem there:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/processing.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="pde/robb2/robb2.pde"></canvas>
    <p>experiments with processing...</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not experienced with processing.js, but it's bad practice and can sometimes cause problems to not have the call to `size()` be the first line in `setup()`. It's also frowned upon to use variables as the parameters to `size()`. I don't know enough to say why either of those things are true (your code looks innocuous enough), but that's what I've heard from the smarter people around here :)

Comment: I tried both, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @kevinsa5 Using variables for `size()` results in the PDE throwing an error while in JavaScript mode. I'm not sure how that affects an uploaded applet though. Where `size()` appears is not that important. It should be written before `width` and `height` are used though for obvious reasons.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo I was inspired to look it up. From the documentation: "The size() function must be the first line of code, or the first code inside setup(). Any code that appears before the size() command may run more than once, which can lead to confusing results."

Comment: @kevinsa5 Thanks, I clearly didn't know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of reasons I don't understand (I have almost no experience with PJS), the `pix` variable, which is declared as an `int`, can sometimes be something that isn't an `int` in your code. When I inserted `println(pix + ":" + r+","+g+","+b);` at the bottom of the `colorRetriever` method, I got a bunch of numbers like this:

```
7401.5:8,255,3
7431.5:15,255,4
7461.500000000001:0,0,0
7491.499999999999:0,0,0
7521.5:26,255,35
7551.5:34,255,38
7581.499999999998:0,0,0
7611.500000000001:0,0,0
7641.499999999999:0,0,0
7671.500000000002:0,0,0
7701.5:39,255,20
7731.5:25,255,23
7761.500000000001:0,0,0
7791.499999999999:0,0,0
```

And when using these floats as an index to the array, instead of crashing, it just returned zero. I'm not really sure why that's how JS deals with non-integer indexing. And I'm also not sure why an int can have decimal points. Anyways, I hope that helps.

Side note: In the course of my investigation, I learned that you can't resize() an image that you loaded from a different server, for some reason the browser doesn't allow it. If you can't draw an image after resizing it, perhaps that's why.